# grep- Extract text present in one document but absent in other

Tags: linux, grep

I want to do some kind of present-absence analysis. I have three different protein files and I want to identify/extract proteins (they are in simple text form) that are present in one file and absent in others and vice versa.

I assume I can do it using 'grep' command but I am unsure about the specifics. Your help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: [This article](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/grep-command-linux-unix-examples) explains how to use grep with multiple files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the pipeline operator to join the commands:

```
cat <file_name> | grep <text you want to identify>
```

e.g.:

```
cat file_1.txt | grep "text"
```

Comment: `cat` is redundant -- just use `grep <pattern> <files>`